# Can I use Nvidia GPU from virtual machine?

Tags: nvidia, virtualization

I will get a Windows machine soon. This machine has a Nvidia GPU
Ideally. If I install Ubuntu in a Virtualbox (or other virtualization method), will I be able to access and use this GPU for CUDA programming?

EDIT:
I have been provided a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92772/access-cuda-from-a-ubuntu-virtual-machine) where it says I couldn't. :(

I found [another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627565/is-it-possible-to-develop-a-cuda-program-in-a-virtual-machine-that-has-a-ubuntu) where it says I could

So in the end, I would welcome answers from people who have tried it (and hopefully succeed :) )

Comment: Dual boot and virtualbox are two completely different. In dual boot, OS can take advantage of all features of the system but in vitualisation, it can't.

Comment: I know, and that is why I wrote "let's not talk about it". And that is why I am asking the question: I would like to know if I can use the GPU through virtualization without problems

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use NVIDIA GeForce M310 on Ubuntu 12.10 running as guest in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202926/how-to-use-nvidia-geforce-m310-on-ubuntu-12-10-running-as-guest-in-virtualbox)

Comment: Not really. First the question is more than 7 y.o. and in windows 7. The question is very specific, including themes such as Unity that isnt related to mine. Then the answers talk about PCI(?) and one commentator says it is not possible. So it does not answer my question which deals with GPU and CUDA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access CUDA from a Ubuntu virtual machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92772/access-cuda-from-a-ubuntu-virtual-machine)

Comment: Did you ever find a good answer?